# Java class in jsp

Tags: java, class, jsp, liferay, portlet

so i dont know how i import a java class correctly. Im working with eclipse tomcat 7 and liferay. 
in liferay is a directory with img files i'll open the directory with java. thats works fine (local) an i get an array with the paths. so i will create a portlet in liferay in jsp and get the array in jsp. any ideas? 
 my jsp :

```
<%@ page import ="OpenDir" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.File"%>
```

```
<%=
    OpenDir.Dir()
%>
```

my java:

```
package life_ray;

import java.io.File;

public class OpenDir {

    public static void Dir() {

        int i = 0;
        File directory = new File(
                "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\");
        File[] contents = directory.listFiles();
        for (File f : contents) {
            f.getAbsolutePath();
            i++;
        }
        String[] name = new String[i];

        i = 0;
        for (File f : contents) {
            name[i] = f.getAbsolutePath();
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        for (File f : contents) {
            name[i] = f.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println("<img src=\"" + name[i] + "\" alt=\"\">");
            i++;
        }

    }
}







so here is my error:
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. life_ray.OpenDir resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /view.jsp
OpenDir cannot be resolved
4: <body>
5: 
6:  <%=
7:      OpenDir.Dir()
8:  %>
9: 
10:
```

Comment: while importing OpenDir try passing fully qualified class name on the top import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go with the answers already made, it might make sense to start to refactor your code:

Java:

```
package life_ray;

import java.io.File;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;

public class OpenDir {

    public static File[] listSamplePictures() {
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\");
        return f.listFiles();
    }

    public static void printSamplePictures(JspWriter w) {
        File[] files = listSamplePictures();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            w.println("<img src=\"" + files[i].getAbsolutePath() + "\" alt=\"\">");
        }
    }

}
```

JSP:

```
<%
    java.io.File[] files = life_ray.OpenDir.listSamplePictures();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        out.println("<img src=\"" + files[i].getAbsolutePath() + "\" alt=\"\">");
    }
%>
```

or

```
<%
    life_ray.OpenDir.printSamplePictures(out);
%>
```

Comment: wow okay this forum is very fast i think :D. thanks for this. So in my first code of java i get an output in the console of all files in the directory with my html code in front and behind the past. i'll use this to import anyway in my view.jsp where more html code and so i will present the pictures in the directory.

Comment: Yes, you need to use the `out` implicit variable in the JSP to get the Java to contribute to the JSP's output. This page shows the implicit variables - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm

Comment: in your code w.println isn't correct. eclipse shows an error: the method println(string) is undefined for the type Writer.

Comment: your solution looks really better thanks. but if i'll use the class and methods in my view.jsp it always marks my pakage... life_ray cannot be resolved...

Comment: Yes you are correct, println is not a Writer method, it is a JspWriter method. I've fixed the answer. If the server can't find your package then I guess your .class or .jar isn't on the classpath for your web application.

Comment: Thank you. yeah i will export my class into a jar file but i can only exort main classes. any solutions to export withou a main? if have the jar i have to copy it into web-inf/lib right? do i have to compile the portlet? and then i can use the portlet in liferay? i am desperate...

Comment: If your web app has a `WEB-INF/classes` folder, as per the standard, then you should be able to put your classes in there and not have to package them in a jar. So your class would be located at `<WEBAPP>\WEB-INF\classes\life_ray\OpenDir.class`.

Comment: okay <webapp> is then the direction in the websever? or in the portlet?

Comment: I have fixed it, but I changed the import, not the method.

Comment: ah okay. but it doesnt work :( the import javax.servlet cannot be resolved. and JspWriter cannot resolved to a type.

Comment: That's a JSP class so you need to compile with that class on your classpath. I don't know your environment so can't help there. You can change the JspWriter import back to Writer and use writeln instead of println.

Comment: how i can compile with that class on my classpath? have i to copy the .class file into the web-inf folder?

Comment: I don't know what your development environment is, so can't say how you would do it.

Comment: okay somthing goes on. so last error in my view.jsp the mehtod printSamplePictures(JspWriter) is undefined for the type OpenDir. my OpenDir looks like yours.

Comment: An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /view.jsp
The method printSamplePictures(JspWriter) from the type OpenDir refers to the missing type JspWriter
5: <body>
6: 
7:  <%
8:   OpenDir.printSamplePictures(out);
9:  %>
10: 
11:

Comment: You need jsp-api.jar as well for `JspWriter`.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println()` will print messages in your stdout (that would be the server log or the console you started your server from). You need to print stuff using `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()` if you want that to get shown in the web page.

However, what you've shown is a really weird way to write java web applications and make use of JSP...

Comment: Of course, you'll only get to notice the above once you import your class correctly, as shown by @NilsH.

Answer (score 1):

You class `OpenDir` resides in a package named `life_ray`. So you need to change your import to

```
<%@ page import ="life_ray.OpenDir" %>
```

I wouldn't recommend having underscore in package names though.

**Edit:**

Also, you're trying to output the value of the `Dir()` method, which is void, so you won't get any output besides in your log file. As mentioned in another answer, your pattern is a weird way of writing a web application.

Comment: It would help if you included some more details about your error.

Comment: do you know where the files have to be? the portlets are on the tomcat webserver. my java file actually on my workflow on local c:\ i'll post the error.

Comment: All your classes need to be on the web application classpath. Having a lone java file somewhere else won't work. Add it to your project, either as a dependant jar file, or within your portlet.

Comment: okay so i have to export into a jar file an put in my portlet?

Comment: okay i'll try it. but if i try to export can only export java files with a main?